# ValueInjecter to ignore cases when mapping properties

Tags: c#, valueinjecter

For example, I want to map property Foo.ID to Bar.Id, is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create your own `ConventionInjection` where you compare the property names case insensitivly:

```cs
public class IgnoreCaseInjection : ConventionInjection
{
     protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
     {
         return String.Compare(c.SourceProp.Name, c.TargetProp.Name, 
                               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0;
     }
}
```

And you need to use it with

```cs
var foo = new Foo() { ID = 1};
var bar = new Bar();
bar.InjectFrom<IgnoreCaseInjection>(foo);
```